# CoreData objects not stying deleted

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I have a UItableView where I am showing a list of projects. You can select and deselect this list of projects.

When the user selects an item from the tableview then I add that dictionary to my coredata

when the user deselects an item from the tableview then I delete that dictionary from my coredata.

every thing works fine in that respect as i log the coredata objects at each select and deselect so I can see there is 1 2 or 3 items depeneing if i have selected them then if i deselect say item 3 it only logs 1 and 2.

So I know those functions are working fine. Now the next thing I have implemented which is the bit thats going wrong is when the tableview displays, I check to see if there are any items from my coredata then when i find the item that relates to the current cell I add an accessory tick. this is to show which values you have saved to core data already.

now the weird thing is, is previously i removed item 3 from coredata and had it confirmed by reading the coredata values and seeing only 1 & 2 existed. then rebuilt the application to check and make sure that the function is working properly that assigns ticks when the view loads. once the view loads items 1 2 and 3 are all selected again..... even though 3 shouldnt.

I am not sure what i am doing wrong but this is my coredata delete function thats called on deselect

```
// Deleting values/tables from coredata entity
- (void)deleteSingleObject:(NSString *)entityDescription Dictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityDescription inManagedObjectContext:__managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSString *projectIDString = [dictionary objectForKey:@"ProjectID"];
    NSPredicate *p=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"projectID == %@",projectIDString];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:p];


    NSError *error;
    NSArray *items = [__managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    for (NSManagedObject *product in items) {
        [__managedObjectContext deleteObject:product];
    }

}
```

and this is how i assign the ticks when the view loads

```
// check if cell needs accessorytick
    for (int i = 0; i < [projectListReadFromCoreDataMutableArray count]; i++) {
        NSDictionary *tempReadCoreDataDictionary = [projectListReadFromCoreDataMutableArray objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([[tempReadCoreDataDictionary objectForKey:@"ProjectID"] isEqualToString:[projectDictionary objectForKey:@"ProjectID"]]) {
            projectListCustomCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }
    }
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.
if you need more information or code let me know but these are the two core parts that I think are the reason for this not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are deleting the object from the Managed Object Context, but you are never saving such modification to the persistent store.

Quoting the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/articles/cdCreateMOs.html)

> Just as a new object is not saved to the store until the context is saved, a deleted object is not removed from the store until the context is saved

That's why the objects are there again when you reload the application.

You have to save the MOC to the persistent store to make the deletion permanent, i.e. something like

```
NSError *error = nil;
if (![_managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    // handle error      
}
```

Comment: oh man.. this worked perfectly. I looked at this perice of code somewhere before but left it out because i thought it was just for catching errors.. whoopsie.. thanks for your help it worked perfectly. I will accept your answer once the time is up :)

Comment: @HurkNburkS I'm glad you solved the issue. Anyway you should go ahead and read the doc I linked in order to understand better the structure of Core Data.